# How to use Order By and With clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using following SQL query to fetch set of records.

```
;WITH SFPIPELINE AS (
    SELECT
        PIPELINE_STRING,
        PACKET_NUMBER,
        PIPELINE_NUMBER
    FROM
        [RTMASTER].[DBO].[SF_PIPELINE]
    WHERE
        PIPELINE_STRING IN (
            'SOLUTION_TEST',
            '2018.01_SVC_SANDBOX',
            '2018.01_SVC_ENG'
        )
        AND PACKET_NUMBER IN (98, 1090, 1092)
),
PROJ_INST_PIPELINE AS (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT PIP.PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE_ID,
        PIP.PROJECT_INSTANCE_ID,
        PIP.PACKET_NUMBER,
        PIP.PROJECT_NUMBER,
        PIP.SOURCE_SET_INSTANCE,
        SFP.PIPELINE_STRING
    FROM
        PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE PIP
        INNER JOIN SFPIPELINE SFP ON PIP.PACKET_NUMBER = SFP.PACKET_NUMBER
        AND PIP.PIPELINE_NUMBER = SFP.PIPELINE_NUMBER
        AND PIP.ACTIVE = 1
        AND PIP.PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE_ID >= 20481038
),
PROJ_INST_BASE AS (
    SELECT
        PIP.PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE_ID,
        PIP.PROJECT_NUMBER,
        PIP.PACKET_NUMBER,
        PIP.PIPELINE_STRING,
        PIP.SOURCE_SET_INSTANCE,
        PIP.PROJECT_INSTANCE_ID,
        PIB.ORIGINAL_PROMOTER,
        PIB.DEV_INSTANCE,
        PROJECT_TYPE_NUMBER,
        PIB.SUBVERSION_PROJECT_REVISION,
        PIB.SUBVERSION _PROJECT_URL,
        PIB.Front_End,
        PIB.Back_End
    FROM
        PROJECT_INSTANCE_BASE PIB
        INNER JOIN PROJ_INST_PIPELINE PIP ON PIB.PROJECT_INSTANCE_ID = PIP.PROJECT_INSTANCE_ID
        AND PIP.PROJECT_NUMBER = PIB.PROJECT_NUMBER
        AND PIB.PROJECT_TYPE_NUMBER IN (5, 105, 106)
),
SF_PROJ AS (
    SELECT
        PJTINST.PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE_ID,
        PJTINST.PROJECT_INSTANCE_ID,
        PJTINST.PROJECT_NUMBER,
        PJTINST.PIPELINE_STRING,
        PJTINST.ORIGINAL_PROMOTER,
        PJTINST.SOURCE_SET_INSTANCE,
        PJTINST.PROJECT_TYPE_NUMBER,
        PJTINST.PACKET_NUMBER,
        SFP.PROJECT_NAME,
        PJTINST.SUBVERSION_PROJECT_REVISION,
        PJTINST.SUBVERSION_PROJECT_URL,
        PJTINST.Front_End,
        PJTINST.Back_End
    FROM
        DBO.SF_PROJECT SFP
        INNER JOIN PROJ_INST_BASE PJTINST ON SFP.PROJECT_NUMBER = PJTINST.PROJECT_NUMBER
),
USER_DETAIL AS (
    SELECT
        SFP.PROJECT_NAME,
        SFP.PROJECT_NUMBER,
        SFP.PROJECT_TYPE_NUMBER,
        SFP.SOURCE_SET_INSTANCE,
        SFP.PACKET_NUMBER,
        SFP.PIPELINE_STRING,
        SFP.SUBVERSION_PROJECT_REVISION,
        SFP.SUBVERSION_PROJECT_URL,
        SFP.PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE_ID,
        SFP.PROJECT_INSTANCE_ID,
        AIAA.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
        SFP.Front_End,
        SFP.Back_End
    FROM
        SF_ASSOCIATE_INFO_ALL_ASSOCIATES AIAA
        INNER JOIN SF_PROJ SFP ON AIAA.OPER_ID = SFP.ORIGINAL_PROMOTER
),
FINAL AS (
    SELECT
        UD.PROJECT_NAME,
        FP.Feature_Number,
        UD.PROJECT_NUMBER,
        UD.PROJECT_TYPE_NUMBER,
        UD.SOURCE_SET_INSTANCE,
        UD.PACKET_NUMBER,
        UD.PIPELINE_STRING,
        UD.SUBVERSION_PROJECT_REVISION,
        UD.SUBVERSION_PROJECT_URL,
        UD.PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE_ID,
        UD.PROJECT_INSTANCE_ID,
        UD.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
        UD.Front_End,
        UD.Back_End
    FROM
        [RTMaster].[dbo].[Feature_Projects_History] FP
        INNER JOIN USER_DETAIL UD ON FP.Project_Instance_Pipeline_ID = UD.PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE_ID
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    FINAL
```

Query is working fine only thing is the records are not sorted.

I want to use order by on PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE_ID so that all the rows are sorted. When I use ORDER BY clause seeing following error.

Error:
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Not sure how to use Order By and With Clause together.

Any thoughts!

Comment: Don't put the `ORDER BY` in the CTE, put it in the final statement (the error does tell you the problem here).

Comment: `TOP` and `FOR XML` are SQL Server keywords

Comment: @HoneyBadger Noted

Comment: @Larnu thanks for hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below i just used  `PROJECT_NAME` in `order by`

```
WITH SFPIPELINE AS     
                    (SELECT PIPELINE_STRING, PACKET_NUMBER, PIPELINE_NUMBER FROM [RTMASTER].[DBO].[SF_PIPELINE]    
                    WHERE PIPELINE_STRING IN ( 'SOLUTION_TEST', '2018.01_SVC_SANDBOX', '2018.01_SVC_ENG')    
                    AND PACKET_NUMBER IN (98, 1090, 1092)),   
                PROJ_INST_PIPELINE AS   
                    (SELECT DISTINCT PIP.PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE_ID, PIP.PROJECT_INSTANCE_ID, PIP.PACKET_NUMBER, PIP.PROJECT_NUMBER, PIP.SOURCE_SET_INSTANCE, SFP.PIPELINE_STRING FROM PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE PIP  
                    INNER JOIN SFPIPELINE SFP ON PIP.PACKET_NUMBER = SFP.PACKET_NUMBER AND PIP.PIPELINE_NUMBER = SFP.PIPELINE_NUMBER AND PIP.ACTIVE = 1   
                    AND PIP.PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE_ID >=   20481038),    
                PROJ_INST_BASE AS             
                    (SELECT PIP.PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE_ID, PIP.PROJECT_NUMBER, PIP.PACKET_NUMBER, PIP.PIPELINE_STRING, PIP.SOURCE_SET_INSTANCE, PIP.PROJECT_INSTANCE_ID, PIB.ORIGINAL_PROMOTER, PIB.DEV_INSTANCE,PROJECT_TYPE_NUMBER, PIB.SUBVERSION_PROJECT_REVISION, PIB.SUBVERSION_PROJECT_URL, 
                    PIB.Front_End, PIB.Back_End FROM PROJECT_INSTANCE_BASE PIB INNER JOIN PROJ_INST_PIPELINE PIP ON PIB.PROJECT_INSTANCE_ID = PIP.PROJECT_INSTANCE_ID AND PIP.PROJECT_NUMBER= PIB.PROJECT_NUMBER AND PIB.PROJECT_TYPE_NUMBER IN (5,105, 106)),           
                SF_PROJ AS   
                    (SELECT PJTINST.PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE_ID, PJTINST.PROJECT_INSTANCE_ID, PJTINST.PROJECT_NUMBER, PJTINST.PIPELINE_STRING, PJTINST.ORIGINAL_PROMOTER, PJTINST.SOURCE_SET_INSTANCE, PJTINST.PROJECT_TYPE_NUMBER, PJTINST.PACKET_NUMBER, SFP.PROJECT_NAME,    
                    PJTINST.SUBVERSION_PROJECT_REVISION, PJTINST.SUBVERSION_PROJECT_URL, PJTINST.Front_End, PJTINST.Back_End FROM DBO.SF_PROJECT SFP INNER JOIN PROJ_INST_BASE PJTINST ON SFP.PROJECT_NUMBER = PJTINST.PROJECT_NUMBER),  
                USER_DETAIL AS  
                    (SELECT SFP.PROJECT_NAME, SFP.PROJECT_NUMBER, SFP.PROJECT_TYPE_NUMBER, SFP.SOURCE_SET_INSTANCE, SFP.PACKET_NUMBER, SFP.PIPELINE_STRING, SFP.SUBVERSION_PROJECT_REVISION, SFP.SUBVERSION_PROJECT_URL, SFP.PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE_ID, SFP.PROJECT_INSTANCE_ID, AIAA.EMAIL_ADDRESS, SFP.Front_End, SFP.Back_End  
                    FROM SF_ASSOCIATE_INFO_ALL_ASSOCIATES AIAA INNER JOIN SF_PROJ SFP ON AIAA.OPER_ID = SFP.ORIGINAL_PROMOTER),  
                FINAL AS 
                    (SELECT UD.PROJECT_NAME, FP.Feature_Number, UD.PROJECT_NUMBER, UD.PROJECT_TYPE_NUMBER, UD.SOURCE_SET_INSTANCE, UD.PACKET_NUMBER, UD.PIPELINE_STRING, UD.SUBVERSION_PROJECT_REVISION, UD.SUBVERSION_PROJECT_URL,   
                    UD.PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE_ID, UD.PROJECT_INSTANCE_ID, UD.EMAIL_ADDRESS, UD.Front_End, UD.Back_End  FROM [RTMaster].[dbo].[Feature_Projects_History] FP 
                    INNER JOIN USER_DETAIL UD ON FP.Project_Instance_Pipeline_ID = UD.PROJECT_INSTANCE_PIPELINE_ID) 
                SELECT * FROM FINAL order by PROJECT_NAME -- use here others column name as you need
```